# Using Git with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, git, css, github

I've been trying to find a way to use git with Wordpress in a way that I can have a local directory and sync it to Github without disorganizing XAMPP's file structure. I had the idea of initializing the repo in the theme folder but then I realized that a lot of plugin's keep pertinent data in directories outside the theme folder. For instance if I initialized the theme in the "theme_name" folder it wouldn't carry over data about Advanced Custom Fields which is a plugin I use a lot.

Another idea I had was to initialize the repo from htdocs and use an ignore file to specify which files/directories not to include but I'm not sure which files/directories to exclude. If anyone has an easy way of syncing a Wordpress theme folder with its plugin data to git, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is plugin and theme why not init git on wp-content folder?

and add ignore files on upload folder and plugin based folder that changes a lot like cache. Ignoring some .md might even reduce your repo size.

some .gitignore like:

`/upload/
/cache/
*.md`

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest utilising a WordPress boilerplate structure like [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/)?

I've found that this is the best way to make WordPress nicely compatible with modern development tools such as Git and, as a bonus, composer).
This will require a bit of learning to adapt to the structure, but Bedrock has fantastic documentation.